# .net application which uses SQL Server is to be deployed on three systems including Server also with Windows XP

Tags: .net, sql, windows-xp

i have to run my windows .net application on three clients connected to a server having SQL Server Express and all the systems are having Windows XP , the server too. so will be there any problem of OS in this case? i mean to say that why people use Windows Server 2003 versions for running SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are limits to the number of [inbound connections XP can accept](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882). So it depends on how many connections the client application makes:

> For Windows XP Professional, the maximum number of other computers that are permitted to simultaneously connect over the network is ten. ... For Windows XP Home Edition, the maximum number of other computers that are permitted to simultaneously connect over the network is five

So if they're only opening one connection each, you're probably okay, but it depends on whether there are other types of connections to the machine with SQL Server (e.g. if you're also using file sharing, etc)

The server versions of windows do not impose such limits (although there may be limitations, they're natural limitations based on what the hardware can support, not the artificial limits applied to client versions of windows)

Answer (score 2):

As Damien mentioned, the inbound connection limit on XP can cause some tricky to track down 
issues.

For example, I maintain a server app which heavily utilises WCF services to service a number of concurrent clients. We have had to exclude XP from the list of supported server platforms precisely because of this issue.